# Authorization on Vue.js and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

I'm new to Vue.js, and I have used Laravel 5.4 as back-end for my project. I did the authentication by using Passport on Laravel and Navigation guards on Vue.js to protect my route on front end, but now I want to do authorization after the user successfully authenticated and store his token on local storage, I want to do authorization based on user role (each role has some of the permissions).

Is there any suggestion for a tutorial to follow?

This my auth. package on Vue.js:

```
export default function(Vue) {
    Vue.auth= {
        setToken(tocken,expiration){
            localStorage.setItem('Tocken',tocken);
            localStorage.setItem('expiration',expiration);
        },
        getToken() {
            var token = localStorage.getItem('Tocken')
            var expiration = localStorage.getItem('expiration')
            if(!token || !expiration)
                return null
            if (Date.now() > parseInt(expiration)) {
                this.destroyToken()
                return null
            } else 
                return token
        },
        destroyToken() {
            localStorage.removeItem('Tocken')
            localStorage.removeItem('expiration')
        },
        // enter code here
        isAuthnticated() {
            if(this.getToken()){
                return true;
            } else
                return false; 
        }
    }

    //Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype)
    Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
        $auth:{
            get: ()=>{
                return Vue.auth
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Isn't it 'token' instead of 'tocken'?

Comment: Yeah  token, this what i mean